# Relationship Exists in neo4j but not in Spring @NodeEntity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j

I have a class in my domain called Activity that looks like the following

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
@NodeEntity
public class Activity {

  @GraphId
  private Long id;

  private String title;

  private String description;

  @Relationship(type = "RELATED_TO", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
  private List<Activity> relatedActivities = new ArrayList<>();

  public Activity() {
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  public Collection<Activity> getRelatedActivities() {
    System.out.println("getting relatedActivities");
    System.out.println(relatedActivities);
    return relatedActivities;
  }

  public void addRelatedActivity(Activity activity) {
    this.relatedActivities.add(activity);
  }
}
```

I create relationships using the following repository class:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "relationships", path = "relationships")
public interface RelationshipRepository extends GraphRepository<Relationship> {

  @Query("MATCH (a1:Activity), (a2:Activity) " +
  "WHERE a1.title = {0} AND a2.title = {1}" +
  "CREATE (a1)-[:RELATED_TO]->(a2)")
  void addRelationship(String a1Title, String a2Title);
}
```

I have verified that this code works using the neo4j browser, which lets me see existing nodes and relationships between them.  However, when I access getRelatedActivities() on an Activity object, it's always an empty array, even if that Activity has other Activity nodes related to it, clearly visible in neo4j.

How can I get the relatedActivites on an Activity to automatically populate based on its relationships correctly?

Comment: How do you load the `Activity` node(s) and what version of SDN are you using?

Comment: I use the @EntityScan annotation with my domain classes' package specified. The Activity NodeEntities are generated properly, as are the Relationship RelationshipEntities, but the relatedActivities list on each Activity node aren't populated.  I'm using version 5 of SDN.

Comment: Could you check my example and compare it to your code? Starting with the test here (https://github.com/meistermeier/sdn-showcase/blob/master/src/test/java/com/meistermeier/neo4jsdn/sdnshowcase/RelationshipTest.java) and then have a look through the classes involved.

Comment: I don't have the annotations EnableNeo4jRepositories EnableTransactionManagement EnableNeo4jAuditing or EnableAsync on my Application. In my Activity NodeEntity I initialize my relationship in the declaration like private List<Activity> relatedActivities = new ArrayList<>(); I'm using PagingAndSortingRepository for my repository instead of Neo4jRepository. Would it help if I put my code on GitHub? Sorry to take so much of your time.

Comment: That would really be helpful. The `PagingAndSortingRepository` 'should' not affect it but let's have a look.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - it's up now (I've just .gitignore'd the application.properties file withe neo4j credentials and uri=bolt://localhost) https://github.com/jpetrich/hamgraphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you define the "target" as an `Activity` here

```
@Relationship(type = "RELATED_TO", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
private List<Activity> relatedActivities = new ArrayList<>();
```

but you also have a `RelationshipEntity` class in your code base: `Relationship` with the same type `RELATED_TO`.

When OGM gets the result it tries to match every field but since it converts the relationship type `RELATED_TO` to the `RelationshipEntity` and not an `Activity` object, it does not fill the list in the `Activity` class.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would never have realized this from the documentation.